# In a 2-column document, how to use "longtable" to create a long table that goes to other pages, but still on the same column?

Tags: longtable, two-column, longtblr

I have a document with two uneven columns, and, in one of the two columns I have a long table. I have used `longtblr` to create the long table. However, would it be possible to use `longtable`, instead of `longtblr`, to reproduce the same result? Indeed, if I replace `longtblr` with `longtable`, I get the following error: `Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode`. Here following, the MWE with `longtblr` and the corresponding result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.4} % left column size
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \lipsum[1] % some text on the left column
    \begin{longtblr}[ % a long table on the left column
      caption = {Long Long Long Tabular},
      entry = {Short Caption},
      label = {tblr:test},
    ]{
      colspec = {XXX}, hlines,
      rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
      row{1-2,Z} = {font=\bfseries},
    }
     Head    & Head  & Head    \\
     Head    & Head  & Head    \\
     Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
     Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
     Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
     Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
     Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
     Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
     Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
     Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
     Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
     Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
     Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
     Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
     Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
     Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
     Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
     Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
     Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
     Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
     Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
     Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
     Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
     Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
     Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
     Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
     Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
     Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
     Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
     Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
     Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
     Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
     Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
     Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
     Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
     Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
     Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
     Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
     Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
     Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
     Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
     Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
     Rho     & Sigma & Tau     \\
     Phi     & Chi   & Psi     \\
     Foot    & Foot  & Foot    \\
    \end{longtblr}
    \lipsum[1] % additional text after the long table, still on the left column
    \switchcolumn 
    \lipsum[1] % text on the right column
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]